# Equation with two columns

Tags: equations

How can I write the following equations

[image]

I tried with aligned but it is not working

```
\begin{aligned}
\f_1(x) &=g_0 & \f_1(x) &=g_0 \\
\f_2(x) &=g_1 & \f_2(x) &=g_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots 
\end{aligned}
```

Answer (score 6):

In this case you want to write that with `alignat`, which allows you to specify the amount horizontal separation (`\qquad` in the example below) between the columns.

If you use the `mathtools` package, an "extension" of `amsmath`, then you can align easily the vertical dots and choose between two possible vertical spacing. In the example below I have chosen small vertical space. If you want bigger space use `\vdotswithin{=}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
A &= B &\qquad  C &= D \\
\MTFlushSpaceAbove
&\vdotswithin{=} & &\vdotswithin{=}
\MTFlushSpaceBelow
C &= D &        Y &=K
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of simplifying the code from an `{alignat}{3}` to an `{alignat}{2}` setup; the screenshot is unchanged. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I always get confused with alignat.

Answer (score 4):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\f}{f}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\f_1(x) & =g_0 & \f_1(x) &  =g_0 \\
\f_2(x) & =g_1 & \f_2(x) &  =g_1 \\
\vdots  &      & \vdots  \\
\f_m(x) & =g_m & \f_m(x) &  =g_m \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]